# Bash - create subfolders for folders recently created

Tags: bash, for-loop, find, directory

I want to "join" these two tasks:

```
for dir in /blabla/bleble/*; do (cd "$dir" && mkdir -p Folder1/Folder1a && mkdir -p Folder2); done
```

and

```
find -amin -10
```

How can I do this?
I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
find -amin -2 -exec sh -c '
for dir in /blabla/bleble/*; do (cd "$dir" && mkdir -p Folder1/Folder1a && mkdir -p Folder2); 
done' sh {} +
```

Comment: How are the two related? Do you want to limit the items matched by `/blabla/bleble/*` to those accessed in the last 10 minutes?

Comment: The loop, by the way, would be more simply written as `for dir in /blabla/bleble/*/; do mkdir -p "$dir/Folder1/Folder1a" "$dir/Folder2"; done`.

Comment: @chepner I want to create subfolders only for the folders accessed in the last minutes (actualy is for the folders created, -mmin)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is might do:

```
find /a/b/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -amin -2 \
  -exec sh -c 'for f; do mkdir -p -- "$f/Folder1/Folder1a" "$f/Folder2; done"' "" {} +
```

Breakdown:

`-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` will limit result to current directory only.

`-type d` makes sure you only list directories

`-exec foo "" {} +` will execute `foo` with matches as arguments:

```
foo "" "/a/b/c" "/a/b/john" "a/b/doe"
```

`for f` will iterate over all positional arguments (`$1`, `$2`, ...)

```
for f; do
  mkdir -p -- "$f/Folder1/Folder1a" "$f/Folder2"
done
```

Running `sh -c 'code' arg1 arg2` will set `$0` to arg1, and `$1` to arg2, therefore the empty argument: `foo "" {} +`:

```
% sh -c 'echo $0' john
john
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there aren't so many folders in `/blabla/bleble` that you overflow the command line, you can use `find` to search the target directory. `-prune` prevents recursing into the directories.

```
find /blabla/bleble/* -prune -type d -amin -10 -exec mkdir -p {}/Folder1/Folder1a {}/Folder2 \;
```

If you are using GNU `find` or another version that supports them, use `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` instead to find the top-level subdirectories, no matter how many there are.

```
find /blabla/bleble -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -amin -10 -exec mkdir -p {}/Folder1/Folder1a {}/Folder2 \;
```